# how to load different content with jQuery of div url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i found this code to read first div id container (box4) and get from url data any newer than box4 
that's work well
but my problem is that when load box5 and re run code again with setInterval 7000 it's not read box5 still reading box4

my code:

```
<div id="replaceeeee">
    <div  id="container" class="container">
        <div id="box4"></div>
        <div id="box3"></div>
        <div id="box2"></div>
        <div id="box1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script

```
window.setInterval(function(){

 var ididid=  $('#container').children().first().attr('id');


$.get( "/getnew.php?idmmm="+ididid, function( data ) {
$( ".container" ).prepend( data );
});



}, 7000);
```

Thanks Very Much For you time i found it

```
window.setInterval(function(){

 var ididid=  $('#container').children().first().attr('id');

var targetLink = $('#container div:nth-child(4) ').attr('id');
var targetLink1 = $('#container div:nth-child(6) ').attr('id');


var targetLink3 = $('#container div:nth-child(9) ').attr('id');
var targetLink4 = $('#container div:nth-child(11) ').attr('id');



$.get( "/getnew.php?idmmm="+ididid, function( data ) {
$( "#container" ).prepend( data );


if(data){

    $("#"+targetLink).insertBefore("#"+targetLink1);
    $("#"+targetLink3).insertBefore("#"+targetLink4);

}


});



}, 10000);
```

Comment: can't understand, different variable names, incorrect html structure. You might have to put some effort into asking questions.

Comment: i re edit it with correct jQuery code

Comment: I can't understand what do you want, can you put more information?

Comment: i set an update to understand me

Comment: Please write what you EXACTLY want to do. And don't use 'new' as a variable name, because it's a keyword in JS.

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net

Comment: i need to find add new divs only  by  .load(document.URL +  ' #replaceeeee1'); and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, I guessed a bit and came up with the following:
I think you're trying to continuously send a request with an increased ID to a webservice of some sort, and then prepend that element to your list of div's - and use the prepended elements ID as the source of the next request url parameter?

I put your code in a jsfiddle and modified a bit:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var idOfFirstDiv = $('#container').children().first().attr('id');
    var idAsNumber = parseInt(idOfFirstDiv.substr(3));
    idAsNumber++;
    $.get( "/robots.txt?id="+idAsNumber, function( data ) {
        var newElement = $('<div id="box' + idAsNumber + '">' + data + '</div>');
        $('#container').prepend(newElement);
    });
}, 7000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/clausjensen/gcnxcgjx/

If you had something else in mind, you need to be a bit more specific with your question!

Comment: thanks very much for you help , i update it with my code please check it

Comment: Well .. now I honestly have no clue what you're trying to do.
If you need more help, you need to create a jsfiddle with your code in it and give a more precise description of what the problem is and what you are trying to do.